# How to wrap the elements by div according to the elements tree structure?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have been doing this for 2 days with no luck. I tried in both using `Dom parser class` and loop method but both of them confusing a lot and couldn't get a solution.

**Objective:**
I need to wrap h tags with div. Parent-child relationship is like h1->h2->h3 and so on. So, I need to wrap div according to the tree structure.

**HTML**

```
$html='<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext

<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<h3>some text</h3>
sometext';
```

**Expected output**

```
<div class="sect1">
<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<div class="sect2">
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
</div>
</div>

<div class="sect1">
<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<div class="sect2">
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<div class="sect3">
<h3>some text</h3>
 sometext
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Attempt 1:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

        for ($i = 0; $i < $elements->length; $i++) {            
        $element = $elements->item($i);
        if ($element->tagName == 'h1'){ 
           $wrap1 = $dom->createElement('div');
           $wrap1->setAttribute('class', 'sect1');

            $wrap1->appendChild($element);
            $dom->appendChild($wrap1);
        }
        if ($element->tagName == 'h2'){ 
           $wrap2 = $dom->createElement('div');
           $wrap2->setAttribute('class', 'sect2');

            $wrap2->appendChild($element);
            $wrap1->appendChild($wrap2);
            $dom->appendChild($wrap1);
        }
    }
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$f=file("extractedadd.xhtml");
for($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++){
    if(strpos($f,'<h1 class="title"')!==false);
    $h1[].=$i;  
}
$h2count=0;
$h3count=0;
for($j=0;$j<count($h1);$j++){
  for($k=$h1[$j];$k<$h1[$j+1];$k++){
      if(strpos($f[$k],'<h2 class="title"')!==false){$h2=$h2count+1;}
      if(strpos($f[$k],'<h3 class="title"')!==false){$h3=$h3count+1;}

 }
 if($h2count!=0){
 for($z=1;$z<=$h2count;$z++){
     $to2.="</div>\n";
 }
 $r=str_replace('<h1 class="title"',$to2."</div>\n".'<h1 class="title"',$h1[$j]);
 $to2="";
}//something like this.
```

Pls help! how to get my expected solution?

Comment: Can we assume that the line looks exactly so - all <h are on a separate lines?

Comment: ya all `h` elements are in separate lines

Comment: Then  it simpler to interprete it. i just try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i make a little more difficulty structure

```
$html='<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext

<h2>some text</h2>
one more sometext

<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<h3>some text</h3>
sometext';

$level = 0;
$array = split("\n", $html); // make array of lines
foreach($array as $line)  {
  if (preg_match('/\s*\<h(\d+)/i', $line, $matches)) {
     $l = $matches[1];  // take new level from tag h
     if ($level == $l) echo "</div>\n<div class=\"sect.$l.\">\n"; // the same level
     else {
        while ($level >= $l) {echo "</div>\n"; $level--; }
        while ($level < $l) {echo "<div class=\"sect".$l."\">\n"; $level++; }
     }
  }
  echo $line."\n";   
}
While ($level >= 1) {echo "</div>\n"; $level--; } // close not closed :)
```

[Whatch there working](https://eval.in/374786)

Comment: Thank you so much! works great. But I have a question. Somebdody says `HTML` manipulation should be done only with `dom parser`, if we do by using `regex` and some other else it will crash. Is this true?

Comment: Problem that real html may have many difficulty to exactly understand the point where you are when scaning it. Many attribute, nesting levels and tags and so on. So, my code on html taken from any site will be not working. It is really just text scaning but not building of dom tree at all. While you save the structure of input  string it will be ok

Comment: I stucked into one. I want to save the result into a file. It's little bit confusing from the above code.

Comment: At the beginning `$output = "";` and change  all echos by `$output .= `. At the end use string $output. Or use output buffering

Comment: `$result="";
$level = 0; 
$array = split("\n", $html); 
foreach($array as $line)  {

  if (preg_match('/\s*\<h(\d+)/i', $line, $matches)) { 
     $l = $matches[1];  
     if ($level == $l) $result.= "</div>\n<div class=\"sect$l\">\n"; 
     else {
       while ($level >= $l) {$result.= "</div>\n"; $level--; } 
       while ($level < $l) {$result.= "<div class=\"sect$l\">\n"; $level++; }
     }
  }
  $result.= $line."\n";   
}
While ($level >= 1) $result.= "</div>\n"; $level--; 
       file_put_contents("content.html",$result); `

Comment: I tried like mentioned above and got an error `"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133955567 bytes)"`

Comment: Wow! May be your file huge? Then you need write to output file while making the result

Comment: I tried `$html='<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext

<h2>some text</h2>
one more sometext

<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<h3>some text</h3>
sometext';` this string only not a huge file and I checked in `php.ini` file there was `memory_limit= 128M`

Comment: chang `file_put_contents("content.html",$result);` with `echo $result;` What wiil be?

Comment: Thank you !Works fine. What was the mistake in that code?It seems like both are same.

Comment: I haven't found :(  it was in my code in the answer. i've reloadede from the link

Comment: Last while loop curly braces makes a different but how would with or without curly braces make a different?Aren't both same?

Comment: hmmm that is the reason for memory leakage.. Anyhow thank you so much :)

Comment: for sure, i have no doubt. I just don't understand when i loss it :) . Good luck